# 403 Forbidden when trying to access Tp-link Archer C5 V4 admin interface via OpenVPN

Tags: router, vpn, openvpn, home-networking

What I'm trying to do is to access the Administrator GUI when connected via OpenVPN; the other way is to enable remote management, but that also means it would be accessible to the internet.

Right now, I have set up the OpenVPN server from my TP-Link router, downloaded the configuration file on my smartphone (opened it with OpenVPN app), and when I try to load `192.168.0.1` in my browser, I get a [403 Forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR5Ei.png) error.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an option to allow/deny management from VPN? It is common for routers to block VPN guests from managing the router as a security risk mitigation.

Comment: There could be a multitude of reasons why this is occurring and the most efficient way to resolve would likely be reviewing documentation on TP-Link's support site for your router.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have the toggle Access for All LAN Connected Devices enabled.
([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSiip.png))

You can find it at System Tools > Administration > Local Management